# Getting document.getElementById().InnerHTML to keep changes

Tags: javascript, html

I amtrying to make a website that will hash a string and show the user said hash. My code is as follows:

```
<!-- HTML Part -->

<form>
String: <input type="text" name="stringToHash" value="Enter String Here"><br>
Salt/Hash cycles: <input type="integer" name="Cycles" value="Enter Cycles Here"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="Input(this.form.stringToHash.value, this.form.Cycles.value)">
</form>

<h3 id='hash'>Hash will appear here</h3>

<!-- HTML Part -->

<script>

function Input(string, cycles){

    for(var i=0; i < cycles; i++){

        var string = Hash(Salt(string));

    }


    document.getElementById("hash").innerHTML=string;
    document.getElementById("hash").textContent=string;

};

</script>
```

This does change the text as required but only for a split second so I tried putting a timeout on it but it did not work.

```
function Input(string, cycles){

    for(var i=0; i < cycles; i++){

        var string = Hash(Salt(string));

    }


    setTimeout(write(string), 1000000)

};

function write(string){

    document.getElementById("hash").innerHTML=string;
    document.getElementById("hash").textContent=string;

};
```

**EDIT**
You can see the website [here](https://string-hasher.000webhostapp.com/)

Comment: You're submitting your form and not doing anything to stop it, which then reloads the page

Comment: Change it to `input type="button"` so it doesn't submit the form.

Comment: Why do you set both `innerHTML` and `textContent`?

Comment: when you have an input or button with type submit inside a form tag, every browser will automatically send a request to the server and reload the page so when you click on submit, it changes the "hash" id tag and then reload the page

Comment: @Barmar I set both to reduce problems with older browsers, I don't know if it works I just saw it on a thread elsewhere and don't have access to any older browsers to test from.